# Minecraft Quarry with python

Tags: python, proxy, minecraft

So I am trying to get into using the python library Quarry, but I have had problems with the proxy which is the feature I am trying to use. When I am using the default "proxy_hide_chat.py" example, when I try to load the server in the server list on mc version 1.19.3 it gives this error

```
No name known for packet: (761, 'status', 'upstream', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/todd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/quarry/net/protocol.py", line 205, in get_packet_name
    return packets.packet_names[key]
KeyError: (761, 'status', 'upstream', 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/todd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/quarry/net/protocol.py", line 241, in data_received
    name = self.get_packet_name(buff.unpack_varint())
  File "/home/todd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/quarry/net/protocol.py", line 207, in get_packet_name
    raise ProtocolError("No name known for packet: %s" % (key,))
quarry.net.protocol.ProtocolError: No name known for packet: (761, 'status', 'upstream', 0)
^C[todd@todd minecraftProxy]$ python teleport_proxy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/todd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1334, in startListening
    skt.bind(addr)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

When I try and connect to the server I get the error "Unknown protocol version" in minecraft.

I have tried to set the protocol version to 761 using this:

```
factory.protocol_version=761
```

but it doesn't do anything.

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
"""
"Quiet mode" example proxy
Allows a client to turn on "quiet mode" which hides chat messages
This client doesn't handle system messages, and assumes none of them contain chat messages
"""

from twisted.internet import reactor
from quarry.types.uuid import UUID
from quarry.net.proxy import DownstreamFactory, Bridge


class QuietBridge(Bridge):
    quiet_mode = False

    def packet_upstream_chat_command(self, buff):
        command = buff.unpack_string()

        if command == "quiet":
            self.toggle_quiet_mode()
            buff.discard()

        else:
            buff.restore()
            self.upstream.send_packet("chat_command", buff.read())

    def packet_upstream_chat_message(self, buff):
        buff.save()
        chat_message = self.read_chat(buff, "upstream")
        self.logger.info(" >> %s" % chat_message)

        if chat_message.startswith("/quiet"):
            self.toggle_quiet_mode()

        elif self.quiet_mode and not chat_message.startswith("/"):
            # Don't let the player send chat messages in quiet mode
            msg = "Can't send messages while in quiet mode"
            self.send_system(msg)

        else:
            # Pass to upstream
            buff.restore()
            self.upstream.send_packet("chat_message", buff.read())

    def toggle_quiet_mode(self):
        # Switch mode
        self.quiet_mode = not self.quiet_mode

        action = self.quiet_mode and "enabled" or "disabled"
        msg = "Quiet mode %s" % action

        self.send_system(msg)

    def packet_downstream_chat_message(self, buff):
        chat_message = self.read_chat(buff, "downstream")
        self.logger.info(" :: %s" % chat_message)

        # All chat messages on 1.19+ are from players and should be ignored in quiet mode
        if self.quiet_mode and self.downstream.protocol_version >= 759:
            return

        # Ignore message that look like chat when in quiet mode
        if chat_message is not None and self.quiet_mode and chat_message.startswith("<"):
            return

        # Pass to downstream
        buff.restore()
        self.downstream.send_packet("chat_message", buff.read())

    def read_chat(self, buff, direction):
        buff.save()
        if direction == "upstream":
            p_text = buff.unpack_string()
            buff.discard()

            return p_text
        elif direction == "downstream":
            # 1.19.1+
            if self.downstream.protocol_version >= 760:
                p_signed_message = buff.unpack_signed_message()
                buff.unpack_varint()  # Filter result
                p_position = buff.unpack_varint()
                p_sender_name = buff.unpack_chat()

                buff.discard()

                if p_position not in (1, 2):  # Ignore system and game info messages
                    # Sender name is sent separately to the message text
                    return ":: <%s> %s" % (
                    p_sender_name, p_signed_message.unsigned_content or p_signed_message.body.message)

                return

            p_text = buff.unpack_chat().to_string()

            # 1.19+
            if self.downstream.protocol_version == 759:
                p_unsigned_text = buff.unpack_optional(lambda: buff.unpack_chat().to_string())
                p_position = buff.unpack_varint()
                buff.unpack_uuid()  # Sender UUID
                p_sender_name = buff.unpack_chat()
                buff.discard()

                if p_position not in (1, 2):  # Ignore system and game info messages
                    # Sender name is sent separately to the message text
                    return "<%s> %s" % (p_sender_name, p_unsigned_text or p_text)

            elif self.downstream.protocol_version >= 47:  # 1.8.x+
                p_position = buff.unpack('B')
                buff.discard()

                if p_position not in (1, 2) and p_text.strip():  # Ignore system and game info messages
                    return p_text

            else:
                return p_text

    def send_system(self, message):
        if self.downstream.protocol_version >= 760:  # 1.19.1+
            self.downstream.send_packet("system_message",
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack_chat(message),
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack('?', False))  # Overlay false to put in chat
        elif self.downstream.protocol_version == 759:  # 1.19
            self.downstream.send_packet("system_message",
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack_chat(message),
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack_varint(1))  # Type 1 for system chat message
        else:
            self.downstream.send_packet("chat_message",
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack_chat(message),
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack('B', 0),
                               self.downstream.buff_type.pack_uuid(UUID(int=0)))


class QuietDownstreamFactory(DownstreamFactory):
    bridge_class = QuietBridge
    motd = "Proxy Server"


def main(argv):
    # Parse options
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--listen-host", default="0.0.0.0", help="address to listen on")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--listen-port", default=12345, type=int, help="port to listen on")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--connect-host", default="127.0.0.1", help="address to connect to")
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--connect-port", default=25565, type=int, help="port to connect to")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    # Create factory
    factory = QuietDownstreamFactory()
    factory.connect_host = args.connect_host
    factory.connect_port = args.connect_port

    # Listen
    factory.protocol_version=761
    factory.listen(args.listen_host, args.listen_port)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. If you are trying to fix a problem in your own code, it is your responsibility to try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem first; but failing that, we can only possibly help with code that is actually shown to us.

Comment: Thank you and I have fixed this and added the code I am running.

Answer (score 0):

Try agan the fctory protocol (for minecraft 1.19) 759

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).